# Can implementing Java copy constructor result in same instance?

Tags: java, jpa, java-8, glassfish-4, java-ee-7

I've implemented a copy constructor in Java 8 and use it like this:

```
User user = // some object
LOG.debug("{}", user);
this.userAccount = new User(user);
LOG.debug("{}", this.userAccount);
```

Output:

```
User@2799061
User@2799061
```

It's the same object! How can this be? Is this some kind of optimalization of which I'm unaware?

Also, my 'User' class is a JPA managed entity. Can this somehow interfere?

Comment: It cannot be the same instance of `User`, but the `toString()` method can give the same results and surely it gives.

Comment: The answer to the question in your title is no. Maybe you are not running the code you've shown, maybe the toString method has been overriden, maybe you are unlucky that the default toString method is printing the same thing for two different objects (you could print `user == this.userAccount` instead) etc...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> It's the same object!

No, it isn't. It just results in the same output when you use it with your `LOG.debug` method. If `LOG.debug` is using `toString`, that means it has the same string result from `toString`. This could be because of your implementation of `toString`, or it could be because the object has the same hash code, since the standard `Object#toString` outputs the class name, `@`, and then the hash code in hex. See `Object#toString` [in the Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--) for details, but basically:

> The toString`method for class`Object`returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character`@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:
>
> ```
> getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
> ```

Re your title:

> Can implementing Java copy constructor result in same instance?

No, not in Java.

Comment: For some reason I've never connected the toString() hash and my _own_ implementation of hashCode(). >< I'll accept your answer as soon as SO will let me.

Comment: @matsa: :-) I can *totally* see how that disconnect could happen.